# Run stand alone windows update in windows server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

How can I patch the stand alone windows update package in our workstations? We're using Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: 1) Downloag patch from [here](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Home.aspx) 2) install patch 3) done

Answer (score 0):

Go to the download packages for the packages, download them and execute them.

See also the official help article: [How to download a Windows update manually](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/973135/how-to-download-a-windows-update-manually)

The steps also should be applicable for Windows 2012 R2. In addition there are various tools available that will help you get the files downloaded. Some of them also provide interfaces to install them.